# Android, findViewById returns null

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm writing some code for Android, the matter is that, when I call findViewById it returns me null, and I cannot understand why! I've been wasting my brain since yesterday, but I cannot figure out the solution. The goal is to set a layout as a header for a listView. Here is my code, respectively my header and my page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/bydistance"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/byactivity"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="#ff0000"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/parkList"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="5.0dp">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here my code where I call the addheaderView:

```
public class NearMeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedBundle){
    super.onCreate(savedBundle);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedBundle) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.park_list, container, false);

    //TODO remove
    make_test(v, container);

    return v;
}

public void openTest(View view){
    new LiveComment().show(getChildFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}

public void onClick(View view){
    if (fragmentManager == null)
        fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    //if (view.getId() == R.id.test){
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(new LiveComment(), "livecomment").commit();
}

private void make_test(View v, ViewGroup container) {

    ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.parkList);
    Park[] list = new Park[3];
    list[0] = new Park("parco a", "acquasparta", false, false, 1, 2, 3);
    list[1]=new Park("parco b", "perugia", false, false, 1, 2, 3);
    list[2]=new Park("parco b", "perugia", false, false, 1, 2, 3);
    ParkListAdapter adapter = new ParkListAdapter(v.getContext(), R.layout.small_park_container,list);
    LinearLayout header = (LinearLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.header);
    listView.addHeaderView(header);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

The error is given at

```
listView.addHeaderView(header)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`R.id.header` is inside `v` not inside `container`.

Change

```
LinearLayout header = (LinearLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.header);
```

with

```
LinearLayout header = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.header);
```

about the ViewGroup container to doc says:

> If non-null, this is the parent view that the fragment's UI should be
>   attached to. The fragment should not add the view itself, but this can
>   be used to generate the LayoutParams of the view.

Edit: Since your header view is in another Layout you have to inflate it too:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedBundle) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.park_list, container, false);
    View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.headerlayout, null);
    //TODO remove
    make_test(v, header);

    return v;
}
```

and

```
private void make_test(View v, View header) {

     // your code  

    // you  have to remove LinearLayout header = (LinearLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.header);
    listView.addHeaderView(header);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Comment: I had already tried it. However I've retried, and it gives me the same error

Comment: inside the layout you post why do you put <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> twice? are those two different layout?

Comment: yes! I've defined header as a separated layout. Shouldn't I do?