# findViewById can't find the view of a programmatically generated view

Tags: android

When I call `findViewById()` to get a button (in the form of an `ImageView`), it returns `null`. I have looked over [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264610/findviewbyid-returns-null) [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378431/android-findviewbyid-returns-null) and I can tell that

- `findViewById()` is called *after* `setContentView()`.
- There is only one layout: `activity_main.xml`.
- I am not using `ExpandableListView`.
- Both `findViewById()` and `topbar.findViewById()` return `null`.

What else might I have overlooked?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout>
 <GridView
   android:id="@+id/topbar_grid">
 </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Mainactivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeTopBar();
        initializeMenu();
    }

    private void initializeTopBar() {
        GridView topbar = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.topbar_grid);
        TopBarAdapter topBarAdapter = new TopBarAdapter(this);
        topbar.setAdapter(topBarAdapter);

        ImageView playButton = (ImageView) findViewById(topBarAdapter.playButtonId);
        // Debugging shows playButton is null here
        // Removing the below statement results in the app 
        // being displayed just fine
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                onPlayButtonClick();
            }
        }); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**TopBarAdapter.java**

```
public class TopBarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private View[] views = new View[2];

    public int playButtonId = 2000;
    public int trackLabelId = 2001;

    public TopBarAdapter(Context c){
        context = c;
        createTrackLabel();
        createPlayButton();
    }

    private void createPlayButton(){
        ImageView playButton = new ImageView(context);
        playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_icon);
        playButton.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        playButton.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(50, 50));
        playButton.setId(playButtonId);
        views[1] = playButton;
    }




    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return views.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return views[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return views[position];
    }
}
```

Comment: but you never add the playButton to the view hierarchy of the Activity, or am I missing something?

Comment: @blackbelt: the `playButton` is part of the `TopBarAdapter` which is added to the `GridView`. Removing the event listener displays the app just fine (including the play button).

Comment: but then  are you returning the playButton somehow in the getView method?

Comment: @blackbelt: I have added the rest of the `TopBarAdapter` class. As far as I can tell: yes, it should be returned.

Comment: I see. you should set the onClickListener when you created the object, inside createPlayButton or, better, use `tobbar.setOnItemClickListener`

Comment: @blackbelt: that does make a lot more sense than what I'm doing right now. I'll try it out and get back to you. I'm still curious as to why I can't retrieve the generated element by its ID though, do you have any idea why that is?

Comment: @blackbelt: setting the event listener in the `TopBarAdapter` works perfectly, if you post it as an answer I will accept it. Still very curious why I can't retrieve the element by its ID though.

Comment: well that's a long discussion, but the adapter works with 1 element like 1000. If your getView returns all the elements with same id, which one the system would return? Also we are not considering view's recycle and other mechanism involved to optimize resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should set the `OnItemClickListener` on your topbar:

```
topbar.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
            int position, long id) {

    }
});
```

Comment: I have simply put the `playButton.setOnClickListener()` inside `TopBarAdapter#createPlayButton()`, but I'm assuming your example will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is the playButton added somewhere to your layout? Where it comes from?
The best way to use `findViewById` method is to rely on Android-generater ids, so instead

```
     Button playButton = (Button) findViewById(topBarAdapter.playButtonId);
```

You should rather rely on

Button playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButtonId);

given that `<Button/>` with `id` `playButtonId` is actually a part of your current view's layout specified by `R.layout.activity_main` . When looking for `topBarAdapter` children's id's you should rather call

```
Button playButton = (Button) topBarAdapter.findViewById(R.id.playButtonId);
```

Comment: The `playButton` (It's an `ImageView`, not a `Button`. Mistake in my original post) is part of the `TopBarAdapter` which is the adapter set to my `GridView`. It renders just fine if I don't call the NPE with the event listener: the play button shows up. 

Keep in mind that my button is not entered into the XML so it does not have its ID generated in `R.id`: it is generated in `TopBarAdapter`.